# MEAN correct way to refactor ejs express code

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mean-stack

I've created a website with express and ejs, pulling JSON in from a file in a local file. I'd like to pass the data in from a mongo database and display with an Angular view. I have a good amount of knowledge in express, angular and mongo. Putting it all together and separating the express tasks from the angular tasks has me hung up a bit.

My app is working over in Heroku at http://healingcenter.herokuapp.com/services/ this is the page I'm unclear on how to separate the express and angular tasks.

It is currently set up in express, this was before I researched angular and the MEAN stack. below is the route config.

```
router.get('/services', function(req, res) {
  var myServices = [];
  var entireList = [];
  entireList = appdata.services;
  appdata.services.forEach(function(item) {
    myServices = myServices.concat(item.title);
  });
  res.render('services', { 
    title: 'Services',
    services: myServices,
    list: entireList,
    page: 'servicesList'
  });
});

/* GET services detail page. */
router.get('/services/:servicesid', function(req, res) {
  var myServices = [];
  var entireList = [];

  appdata.services.forEach(function(item){
    if (item.shortname == req.params.servicesid){
      entireList.push(item);
      myServices = myServices.concat(item.title);

    }
  });
  res.render('services', { 
    title: 'Services',
    services: myServices,
    list: entireList,
    page: 'servicesDetail'
  });
});
```

This is pulling in the same data.json file from the app.js file with this line of code.

```
app.locals.appdata = require('./data.json');
```

The page variable is the important part. An if else statement is customizing which data is brought in. That code is here:

```
<div class="services">
       <% list.forEach(function(item){ %>
        <article class="service group">

            <% if (page!= 'servicesDetail') { %>
            <a href="/services/<%= item.shortname %>"><h3><%= item.title %></h3></a>
            <p><%- item.summary %></p>
            <a href="/services/<%= item.shortname %>">more</a>
            <% }else{ %>
            <a class="back" href="/services/#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i> back</a>
            <a href="/services/<%= item.shortname %>"><h3><%= item.title %></h3></a>
            <p><%- item.description %></p>
            <% } %>

        </article>
      <% }); %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you written any angular code for this app yet?  Once you have the page up and rendering, plugging in the variable data is just a matter of making an API call to your express server, and taking that and adding it to your $scope.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess the real question is what would be the best way to create this details page on link click where different information from the JSON object is displayed. I'd like it to work just as it is now, but with the angular and express structure instead of just relying on express.

Comment: The biggest change you'll notice is on the express side, instead of `res.render` you'll be issuing `res.send` to respond with some JSON data to your client.  On the angular side of things, you can take a look at [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) to make the API call to your server.  Then like I said, add the data to your controller's $scope and you can have access to it in the page's HTML.  But there's certainly a lot there to review if you're new to any of it.